# Bulk sessionzed message retrieval using MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How does one use the MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync to retrieve sessionized messages in bulk?. My messages are written to the queue with SessionId. However I dont see any examples on how and where I should specify sessionid when I read messages in bulk. Is it possible to read sessionized messages in bulk using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get sessionized messages in bulk, you should use `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package, just try the console app below:

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace serviceBusTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            string queueName = "";
            string sessionID = "";

            var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
           
            ServiceBusSessionReceiver receiver = client.AcceptSessionAsync(queueName, sessionID).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var messages = receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(maxMessages: 10).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            foreach (var message in messages) {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
            }

           
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What about topics? Is there an option to subscribe and get topic messages in bulk?

Comment: @Codecrasher99 you can find all code sample in this offical guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions let me know if it helps :)

Comment: @Codecrasher99 How's going? Has your issue got resolved?